# Executando métodos através de atalhos de teclado configuráveis

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que tem algumas funções (ex: F12 -> Fechar o sistema).
No sistema tem o form de parâmetros, e neste form gostaria que o cliente pudesse escolher qual o atalho para cada função.
detalhe: cada função é um método no código fonte, então só preciso referenciar um atalho a um método em tempo de execução.

```
if(e.keycode == Keys.F12)
{
   FecharSistema();
}
```

Este código e como funciona o sistema hoje, mas agora tem um form de configurações onde seria possível alterar o atalho do F12 para o F10. Resumindo, deixar para o cliente escolher qual função terá em cada tecla. Atualmente o F1 - Abre o caixa, F2 - inicia uma venda, F12 - Fecha o sistema. Porém cada cliente quer o atalho em botões diferentes. Foi desenvolvido um form onde é possível que o usuário escolha qual tecla realizará cada função.

Como alterar o código para que o atalho seja personalizável?

Comment: Ué, muda o if e pronto.  `if(e.keycode == TECLA_DE_FECHAR_O_SISTEMA)`.

Comment: não posso alterar no código, pois não tenho como adivinhar qual tecla o cliente vai escolher. Cada um quer um atalho diferente, o sistema é personalizável!

Answer (score 2):

**Há dois possíveis casos**, utilize o que você achar mais conveniente ao seu projeto.

---

### Com foco

O primeiro é o Form só pegar Keys caso ele esteja com o foco, caso ele esteja minimizado ele não irá pegar. Esse caso é mais simples.

```
    // Coloque no .cs do seu Form
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if(keyData == Keys.F12) // Compara a tecla pressionada
               FecharSistema(); //Realiza o método desejado

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

---

### Sem Foco

Nesse caso, mesmo se o Form estiver minimizado ele pode receber o comando da tecla pressionada, utilizando *Global Hotkey* com P/Invoke numa [função do Windows](http://fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20do%20Windows.). Recomendo este [artigo sobre *Global Hotkey*](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/). Também tem o [código da classe GlobalHotkey](http://pastebin.com/HEnsDLiu) descrito no artigo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  GlobalHotkey hk1;
  public Form1()
  {
     this.hk1 = new GlobalHotkey(0, Keys.F12, this); // Registra o F12 para este formulário, "this".
     this.hk1.Register();
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
      if (m.Msg == Hotkeys.Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID) // Compara se a mensagem é uma tecla registrada
      {
           if ((IntPtr)this.hk1.GetHashCode() == m.WParam) // Verifica se a tecla pressionada é a que registramos em nosso código.
             FecharSistema();
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);    
  }
```

---

**Se você quer um sistema personalizável**, crie um controle e no Evento "*KeyUp*". Nesse caso eu utilizei um Textbox para pegar a Key que o usuário desejaria.

```
    Keys KeyPersonalizada;

    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       KeyPersonalizada = e.KeyCode;
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
         if(keyData == KeyPersonalizada) // Compara a tecla pressionada é igual a personalizada
             FecharSistema(); //Realiza o método desejado

         return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```